# Slicing String based on uncertain values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to slice the below string

```
data = 'INFO: 2585,1,194,-105,-8,-97,14'
```

here I need to get values **194 & -97** for that I can do

```
print(data[13:16],data[25:28])
result - 194 -97
```

But say if the value changes from

> 194 to 9999
>
> i.e some other value having extra digits

then the slicing would become incorrect kindly suggest a way to handle this

Comment: extract the numbers part and split it on comma

Comment: @Jan Wilamowski if possible can u give a short exp if i do data.split(",') all elements will get split  but i only need 194 & 97 here

Comment: will the positions of the numbers you want to extract change? i.e. now you want the 3rd and 6th numbers - is that always the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split on `': '` and then on `','` and take the relevant numbers using their indices:

```
data = 'INFO: 2585,1,194,-105,-8,-97,14'
s = data.split(': ')[1].split(',')
first, second = s[2], s[-2]
```

Output:

```
('194', '-97')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split() function, it splits the string by pointer, for example
"194,192,196".split() will return an array of three elements: ["194","192","196"].
You can use this code:

```
data = 'INFO: 2585,1,194,-105,-8,-97,14'

data = data.split(": ")[1].split(",")
print(data[2], data[5])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regulat split

```
data = 'INFO: 2585,1,9999,-105,-8,-97,14'


data2 = data.split(",")
print(data2[2],data2[5])

Output - 9999 -97
```